# How to check if a condition is verified in a string

Tags: r, string

I have these strings

```
myString<-c("NA,1,2,3,7,9,45","NA,1,100,","NA,23,24,25,27")
```

If i want to check if the value `1` is present in a string I use this code:

```
str_detect(myString,"1")

[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Now I want to check if a value `>=30` is present in a string.

I have no idea how to do it

Comment: `str_detect(myString,"1")` will also match e.g. `10`, `11` or `100`.

Answer (score 3):

You can extract all numbers, convert them to numeric and test for =>30:

```
sapply(regmatches(myString, gregexpr("\\d+", myString)), \(x) any(as.numeric(x)>=30))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or direct as a regex using `grepl` where `[3-9]` are numbers from 3 to 9, `\\d` is any number, `\\d{3,}` are numbers with 3 digits and `|` stand for or.

```
grepl("[3-9]\\d|\\d{3,}", myString)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Benchmark

```
bench::mark(
Maël = sapply(strsplit(myString, ","), \(x) any(na.omit(type.convert(x, as.is = TRUE)) >= 30)),
GKi1 = sapply(regmatches(myString, gregexpr("\\d+", myString)), \(x) any(as.numeric(x)>=30)),
GKi2 = grepl("[3-9]\\d|\\d{3,}", myString) )
#  expression      min  median itr/s…¹ mem_a…² gc/se…³ n_itr  n_gc total…⁴ result
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:t>   <dbl> <bch:b>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t> <list>
#1 Maël        110.2µs   118µs   8367.    11KB    10.2  4101     5   490ms <lgl> 
#2 GKi1         86.3µs  92.9µs  10573.    33KB    12.4  5128     6   485ms <lgl> 
#3 GKi2         10.2µs  10.9µs  90135.      0B     0   10000     0   111ms <lgl>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should create numeric strings with `type.convert` and check:

```r
sapply(strsplit(myString, ","), \(x) any(na.omit(type.convert(x, as.is = TRUE)) >= 30))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```